# ifstream can't locate file?

Tags: c++, xcode4, ifstream

I'm trying to read a file called "sample.txt" but whenever i try to do an `ifstream`, it can never locate the file. So my question is where do you put the file so that it can be located?

```
 ifstream iFile("sample.txt");
```

Comment: That file is expected to be found in the [current working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), whatever that may be.

Comment: You can find the directory it is running from by right clicking the binary under "Products" and selecting "Show in Finder".

Comment: I did put the sample.txt file in the main.cpp directory but whenever i try to do something like   iFile.is_open(); // i get an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution.

1) Open your project in Xcode;

2) Locate the Products folder in the Groups & Files tree on the left side of your Project window;

3) When you expand that folder, you should see the icon for the Unix Executable File (usually a black rectangle);

4) Ctrl-click on that icon and select Show in Finder_ (If you accidentally choose Open With Finder, the Finder will start your program in a Terminal window);

5) Show in Finder should bring up a Finder window showing the contents of the folder which includes your executable. You should see your output files in that window.

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2145737?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify an absolute path the file name is interpreted to be relative to the working directory of the program.

Comment: I did put the sample.txt file where main.cpp file was and I still could not read the file. I also tried                                 ofstream oFile("sample1.txt"); //creates sample.txt file somewhere                                            and when i tried to read sample1.txt file, it worked fine but when i went to the directory to look for it i could not find sample1.txt anywhere. So i'm guessing xcode 4 created sample1.txt file somewhere else or what?

Comment: @cantfindaname88 It just depends what the working directory of your program is, which need not be the directory of the main.cpp. It can be the directory of the executable, or maybe if you start your program from Xcode directly, it could be the directory of the Xcode project (VS does that), but I don't have any experience with Xcode or Apple in general. Just give the file a unique name and search for it. I'm sure it's one of the places I mentioned. Or use some OS function to determine the current working directory.